# require() not defined in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am using electron with Mineflayer. I am trying to send an IPC event to the main process to run Mineflayer there, but when I use `const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')`, I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at choose-server.js:1
```

For some reason, this only happens on the second page. The first page is the login page, wherein I use `const { remote, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");` which gives no error. I change page using

```
window.location = `file://${__dirname}/choose-server.html`;
```

I think the way that I change page has something to do with the error. I have tried switching to import instead of require(), but that did nothing to help. I have nodeIntegration set to true. I import my scripts though `<script src="choose-server.js"></script>`, but I have tried with `require();`. I only get the error, when I press the join button. The button has the same event listener as my minimize, maximize, and close buttons which all work perfectly. The only difference is that the join button's event listener uses ipcRenderer in it, while the others only use remote.getCurrentWindow.

Comment: Your main process should monitor whether your user has successfully signed in. If they did, then use [`Browser.loadFile`](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) to load the next page. I wouldn't implement pages transition logic in the renderer process if I were you. I would orchestrate this from the main process only.

Comment: So should I use ipcRenderer to tell the main process when the user has logged in?